# Device's local images doesn't render on Image component of React Native. (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to make a kind of galery but i found a issue when i try to acess the local files, i used the CameraRoll library of react-native/@comunity to get the info of the images.

The CameraRoll works properly and returns a correct uri of the images, but even trying to acess directly by the path in the source of  it doesn't work, however if i use a external uri the component show the image.
I've tried use directly the uri, in a variable, or in the state (in the Flatlist commented), none of them works.

The app has acess to the Storage to write,read and modify.
The getPhotos method works well and returns me the 2 images that i have in the simulator.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem ?

react-native: 0.64.2
Android 10 (Android Studio)

```
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  async function getPhotos() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && (await hasAndroidPermission())) {
      CameraRoll.getPhotos({
        first: 4,
        assetType: 'All',
      }).then(r => {
        setImages(r.edges);
      });
    }
  }

 function handleGetPhotos() {
    getPhotos();
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <ButtonGet title="Get Photos" onPress={() => handleGetPhotos()}>
        <Text>Get Photos</Text>
      </ButtonGet>

      <Image
        style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
        // source={{
        //   uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png',
        // }} //That works
        source={{
          uri: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210718_112257.jpg',
        }}
        resizeMode={'contain'} //i tried whitout and doesn't change anything
      />

      <FlatList
        data={images}
        keyExtractor={item => item.node.timestamp}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', marginBottom: 15}}>
            <Text>{item.node.group_name}</Text>
            {/* <Image source={{uri: item.node.image.uri}} /> */}
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Object example of r.edges (the null values are because of some options in CameraRoll, i omitted then but works too):

```
node: {
  group_name: 'Download',
  image:{
    fileSize: null, 
    filename: null, 
    height: null, 
    playableDuration: null, 
    uri: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210718_112257.jpg', 
    width: null
  }, 
  location: null,
  modified: 1626550157,
  timestamp: 1626550156,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `include` param in `CameraRoll.getPhotos`. To get height and width you will have to pass `["imageSize"]` param